# Can't access port from outside

Tags: networking, firewall

So I just served up some directory using python SimpleHTTPServer and I'm unable to access port from another machine on the same network. It works fine locally, with localhost:port as well as ip:port but not from another machine. Below are the results for nmap and firewall is inactive.

```
nmap <ip> -p 8080
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-05-16 14:10 IST
Nmap scan report for css-Latitude-E6430 (<ip>)
Host is up (0.00014s latency).

PORT     STATE SERVICE
8080/tcp open  http-proxy

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.05 seconds


sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

nmap from another computer on the same network

```
nmap -p 8080 <ip>
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-05-16 14:07 IST
Nmap scan report for <ip>
Host is up (0.073s latency).

PORT     STATE  SERVICE
8080/tcp closed http-proxy

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 6.76 seconds
```

Yes, it does say closed from another. Checked if the machine is just listening for local requests but nope,

```
netstat -an | grep :8080
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*
```

It's listening on 0.0.0.0

So what could be wrong up here? If more data is needed kindly let me know.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running? Are you using firewalld by any chance? If yes try `firewall-cmd --list-all` to see your current firewall rules

Comment: 18.04 is the version and ```firewall-cmd --list-all yeilds,
public (active)
 target: default
 icmp-block-inversion: no
 interfaces: wlo1
 sources:
 services: ssh dhcpv6-client
 ports:
 protocols:
 masquerade: no
 forward-ports:
 source-ports:
 icmp-blocks:
 rich rules:
```

Ok this is active, something needs to be changed?

Comment: Probably something like this `sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp --permanent` then `sudo firewall-cmd --reload`

Comment: Yes, that worked. Didn't know that something besides ufw existed. Thanks for the info.